# Xcode crashes with assertion error in DVTNSArrayAdditions

Tags: xcode

This happens no matter what project I open, whether it's for iOS or Mac. I've reviewed other causes listed on SO and elsewhere, and have eliminated anything to do with repositories, bad certificates, `project.xcworkspace` and `com.apple.dt.Xcode.*`. This only happens when I open a project. I can view the organizer without a problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the error:

```
Process:         Xcode [3904]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.3.2 (1177)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1177000000000000~6
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 7171108
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [124]

Date/Time:       2012-04-25 14:25:53.522 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50b)
Report Version:  9
Sleep/Wake UUID: 918AC06B-8025-41D9-A37F-809262E52D1C

Interval Since Last Report:          135670 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           10
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  33821 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   10
Anonymous UUID:                      78350ED9-1E4E-47B3-BFA2-60CDC279B7DB

Crashed Thread:  24

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4E2002
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-1193/Framework/Classes/FoundationClassCategories/DVTNSArrayAdditions.m:207
Details:  Assertion failed: object != ((void*)0)
Object:   <__NSArrayM: 0x4028cd680>
Method:   -dvt_addObjectIfAbsent:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x4023dfe00>{name = (null), num = 16}
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000107f5cc8f -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DevToolsCore)
  1  0x0000000104f9b635 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000104f30e78 -[NSMutableArray(DVTFoundationClassAdditions) dvt_addObjectIfAbsent:] (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000104f7136f -[DVTSDK commandLineToolSearchPath] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000107f9e9e4 -[XCCommandLineToolSpecification findExecutable:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x0000000107f6e876 -[PBXCompilerSpecificationGcc executablePathInTargetBuildContext:forLanguageDialect:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x0000000107f6e92e -[PBXCompilerSpecificationGcc discoveredCompilerDriverInfoInBuildContext:forLanguageDialect:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x0000000107f732ab -[PBXCompilerSpecificationGcc2_95_2 compileSourceCodeFileAtPath:ofType:toOutputDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x0000000108049a27 -[XCCompilerSpecificationClang compileSourceCodeFileAtPath:ofType:toOutputDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x0000000107f71a33 -[PBXCompilerSpecificationGcc computeDependenciesForInputNodes:ofType:variant:architecture:outputDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x0000000107fa525b -[XCCompilerSpecification computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:outputDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x000000010803f84e -[XCBuildRuleDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:withOutputDirectory:additionalProperties:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x0000000108038647 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) _computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:inTargetBuildContext:processedPaths:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x0000000108038d25 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14  0x00000001080392c3 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 15  0x000000010802dc0c -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 16  0x000000010803aab0 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17  0x000000010803b450 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18  0x0000000107fa811e -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 19  0x00000001080294d3 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 20  0x0000000107f4bf81 -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 21  0x0000000107f5dc15 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 22  0x00007fff899daf4c __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
 23  0x00007fff899dade4 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
 24  0x0000000107f5d010 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
 25  0x00007fff899daf4c __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x00007fff899dade4 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
 27  0x0000000107fa07e1 -[XCInvocationQueue _processNextInvocationInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 28  0x0000000107fa0c48 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 29  0x00007fff88db774e -[NSThread main] (in Foundation)
 30  0x00007fff88db76c6 __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
 31  0x00007fff8edc08bf _pthread_start (in libsystem_c.dylib)
 32  0x00007fff8edc3b75 thread_start (in libsystem_c.dylib)

UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff899e8faa __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff8f537d5e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff89a732a9 -[NSException raise] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x0000000104f9b635 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000104f30e78 -[NSMutableArray(DVTFoundationClassAdditions) dvt_addObjectIfAbsent:] (in DVTFoundation)
  5  0x0000000104f7136f -[DVTSDK commandLineToolSearchPath] (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x0000000107f9e9e4 -[XCCommandLineToolSpecification findExecutable:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x0000000107f6e876 -[PBXCompilerSpecificationGcc executablePathInTargetBuildContext:forLanguageDialect:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x0000000107f6e92e -[PBXCompilerSpecificationGcc discoveredCompilerDriverInfoInBuildContext:forLanguageDialect:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x0000000107f732ab -[PBXCompilerSpecificationGcc2_95_2 compileSourceCodeFileAtPath:ofType:toOutputDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x0000000108049a27 -[XCCompilerSpecificationClang compileSourceCodeFileAtPath:ofType:toOutputDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x0000000107f71a33 -[PBXCompilerSpecificationGcc computeDependenciesForInputNodes:ofType:variant:architecture:outputDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x0000000107fa525b -[XCCompilerSpecification computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:outputDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x000000010803f84e -[XCBuildRuleDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:withOutputDirectory:additionalProperties:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14  0x0000000108038647 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) _computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:inTargetBuildContext:processedPaths:] (in DevToolsCore)
 15  0x0000000108038d25 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 16  0x00000001080392c3 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17  0x000000010802dc0c -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18  0x000000010803aab0 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 19  0x000000010803b450 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 20  0x0000000107fa811e -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 21  0x00000001080294d3 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 22  0x0000000107f4bf81 -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 23  0x0000000107f5dc15 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 24  0x00007fff899daf4c __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
 25  0x00007fff899dade4 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x0000000107f5d010 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
 27  0x00007fff899daf4c __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
 28  0x00007fff899dade4 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
 29  0x0000000107fa07e1 -[XCInvocationQueue _processNextInvocationInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 30  0x0000000107fa0c48 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 31  0x00007fff88db774e -[NSThread main] (in Foundation)
 32  0x00007fff88db76c6 __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
 33  0x00007fff8edc08bf _pthread_start (in libsystem_c.dylib)
 34  0x00007fff8edc3b75 thread_start (in libsystem_c.dylib)

objc[3904]: garbage collection is ON
abort() called
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Xcode 4.3 by dragging the icon to the trash and reinstalling from the Mac App Store fixed the problem.

Weird.

Edited to add: shortly after this whole thing happened, my hard drive went belly-up. So, it appears this was likely related not to anything Xcodey, but rather to my own failing hard drive. Lesson: backup if you get this error, it may be an indicator of something Really Bad.